# String Replace Date & Time

Tags: php, string, date, time, replace

a line of my XML looks like this:

```
<observation_time_rfc822>Thu, 09 Oct 2014 22:59:16 +0200</observation_time_rfc822>
```

I grab it and give it out:

```
$ob_time= $xml->observation_time_rfc822;
echo $ob_time;
```

The output looks like this:

Thu, 09 Oct 2014 22:59:16 +0200

But what I need should look like this (yes, the funny '%3A' replaces ':')

2014-10-09**+**22**%3A**59**%3A**16

I think string replace can do this, please someone can help me to find out!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Use @Ghost's solution, it correctly handles the timezone offset.

First you need to reformat your date. You do this by parsing it with `strtotime` and formatting it with the `date` function. Those "funny %3A replaces" are actually URL-encoded characters:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($ob_time));
$date = urlencode($date); // 2014-10-09+20%3A59%3A16
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTime` class in this case, then use `urlencode()`:

Example:

```
$ob_time = (string) $xml->observation_time_rfc822;

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $ob_time);
$real_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo urlencode($real_date); // 2014-10-09+22%3A59%3A16
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, because it handles the timezone offset properly too.

Comment: @VictorStanciu yes but if the OP wants a simple solution, yours is much straight forward